# Elasticsearch: fetching all documents with filters

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My objective is to fetch all documents which match filters. The Java doc is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-multi-get.html).

Can I put a filter on the `_mget`? For example, can I get "all docs created before a date" or "all docs missing certain fields"?

Comment: Narrowed to Java. Added constraints to title. Included reference to REST API endpoint in use, _mget.

Comment: Clarified first sentence to include interest in filters.